# Why doesn't Qt see my slot?

Tags: c++, qt, qobject, qtcore, qt-signals

I'm trying to add a context menu to a tree with the following code:

```
void MainWindow::FileTreeContextMenu(const QPoint& pos)
{
    QPoint globalPos = ui->fileTree->viewport()->mapToGlobal(pos);
    QMenu menu;
    menu.addAction("New Group");

    QAction* selectedItem = menu.exec(globalPos);
}

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    ui->fileTree->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu);
    connect(ui->fileTree,
            SIGNAL(customContextMenuRequested(const QPoint&)),
            this,
            SLOT(FileTreeContextMenu(const QPoint&)));
}
```

However, when I run this, I get the following error:

```
QObject::connect: No such slot MainWindow::FileTreeContextMenu(const QPoint&) 
  in ..\src\Fixer\mainwindow.cpp:23
QObject::connect:  (sender name:   'fileTree')
QObject::connect:  (receiver name: 'MainWindow')
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you declared the function as a slot in your class MainWindow?

Comment: Show the header pleaese. You hould have either Q_SLOT or slots there. It is also possible you miss the Q_OBJECT macro in your header...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

It can happen if you omit to declare the slot as a real slot. You can either use the `Q_SLOTS` macros for that or just simply `slots`. In your case, the latter is more adequate because it is just an application and a mainwindow.

You also need to make sure you do not forget to use the `Q_OBJECT` macro in your header file.